# How to fix CodeIgniter routes

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in framework please help to solve this. I am working in CodeIgniter. I want to have clean URLs like this: `example.com/index.php/6/title`

`index.php/6` is a post ID and title is a Page title.
I want to get data by post ID.

Controller function:

```
public function watch(){
            echo id;

        }
```

How to get this clean URL using routes. I am trying this route but it's not working:

```
$route['(:num)/(:any)'] = 'front_controller/watch/';
```

Comment: what is your expected result? @kidly

Comment: what is your base url.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by clean url..Post what URL you want to achieve as almost any URL can achieved using Codeigniter Routes

Comment: my base url is loclhost/project1/

Comment: Do you only want to remove 'index.php' from the URL ?

Comment: @kidly check my answer below...Hope it is what you required.

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this for routing to `watch()` function in `Front_controller` with 2 parameters `id` and `title`

```
$route['(:num)/(:any)'] = 'front_controller/watch/$1/$2';
```

Also you should accept 2 paramets in your controllers function too as :

```
function watch($id,$title)
{
    echo $id;
    echo $title;
}
```

Let me know in case of any queries.